# Retrieve only the category ID from URL

Tags: php, regex, seo

I have my URL structure as www.site.com/listings/232-real-estate where 232 is the category ID and real-estate as my category name.

I want to retrieve only the numeric ID, to be used to extract data from the database using the category ID. How do I do that?

Comment: @dbaupp, sorry, edited my question. The ID is 232.

Comment: What language do you want to use? php, or awk is OK too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something as simple as:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('#(\d+)#', $url, $matches);
$catid = $matches[0];
?>
```

But this does not have adequate checks in place. Ideally, you want to split on basis of /:

```
<?php

$elements = explode('/',$url);
$category = $elements[2];
$subelements = explode('-',$category);
$categoryid = intval($subelements[0]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
id = preg_replace('/^.*\/([0-9]*)-[^\/]*$/','$1')
```

This assumes that the last `/` in the url is just before the category ID.

Answer (score 0):

If `232-real-estate` is stored in the variable `$var` you can get the ID using:

```
$id = strtok($var, '-');
```

Incidentally, it is then trivial to get the name:

```
$name = strtok(''); // returns: estate-agent
```